# Order in Promise/Async/Await (Interview Question)

Tags: javascript, async-await, promise, es6-promise

### Question:

```js
new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log(1)
  resolve()
}).then(async () => {
  console.log(2)
}).then(async () => {
  console.log(3)
})

new Promise((resolve) => {
  console.log('a')
  resolve()
}).then(() => {
  console.log('b')
}).then(() => {
  console.log('c')
}).then(() => {
  console.log('d')
}).then(() => {
  console.log('e')
})
```

### Answer:

1
a
2
b
c
d
3
e

But I think answer is.... 1 a 2 b 3 c d e

Please help to share how to think to get answer detailed. Thanks.

Comment: This is a horrible interview question because nobody in the real world needs to know the precise way this would play out.  If you were relying on a specific order with independent promise chains, then you have really, really poorly written code.  If a specific order is needed, then one codes it to make it deliver that order without relying 0n minor spec details which occasionally even change as the language evolves.  So, while there may be a curiosity, as far as I'm concerned, **this isn't a useful programming problem and I'd state that in my interview answer and explain why**.

Comment: what @jfriend00 said, if this is the sort of question they'd ask of you I'd leave.

Comment: @jfriend00  Ya, I got it. But It really confused me that what happen in my node.js?

Comment: I run this code in two different environments and received two different results. Chrome says 1 a 2 b c d 3 e, where [online visualizer](https://www.jsv9000.app/) says 1 a 2 b 3 c d e.

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi can i ask what i means?

Comment: It means that my current knowledge of JS internals can't be used to understand why  it happens :( The first two logs are clear. They are synchronous. All other calls are seems to be microtasks. But why it switch to `3` at the end and after prints e it is strange to me.

Comment: Note that the use of `async` functions here will probably trigger a different outcome based on the age of the JS engine because the spec was updated to take slightly fewer cycles for `async` functions a few years ago.  Yes another reason why relying on a specific ordering in cases like these is bad programming.

Comment: @jfriend00 I think your reply is very solid. But I sill confused  that if JS is single thread language, why these micro-task is excused so strangely and ......random

Comment: Single threaded applies to your own Javascript, not to internal asynchronous operations such as reading from a file or sending and http request to a server and getting a response.  Those can run in parallel and you can then use promises to track their completion.  You start them in the single threaded JS and then they run on their own until when they complete, they insert something in the event queue so the JS engine will run their completion logic when it gets a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First I would explain that nobody should ever rely on precise timing between two separate promise chains.  They run independently of one another and as soon as you insert **any real world asynchronous operations** in either of those promise chains (which all real-world programming would contain), **then the timing of each chain is entirely unpredictable vs. the other**.

**Instead the timing in real code depends upon the timing of the asynchronous operations, not on anything else.**  Imagine that each of the steps in this promise chain was reading a file or doing some random delay.  Those are entirely unpredictable operations so which chain does what first depends upon the timing of the actual asynchronous operations, not on what is shown in this example.

So, trying to dissect the details of exactly when each item goes into the promise job queue and when it gets serviced is a complete waste of programming time and not useful in any real programming problem.

Further, if you really need a specific ordering of operations, then you don't program with two independent promise chains.  Instead, you use promise flow-of-control tools (like chaining everything into one chain or using `Promise.all()`, `Promise.race()`, etc...) to guide the execution/completion order into exactly what you want it to be regardless of the detailed inner workings of the promise implementation.

Then, I would explain the basics of how the promise queue works by walking through the first two links of one of the promise chains just to show that I understand how a promise gets resolved, gets added to the promise queue and then, when control is about to return to the event loop, the oldest item in the promise queue gets to run and call its `.then()` or `.catch()` handlers.  This is just to illustrated that you understand the basics of how promises are scheduled and that they get serviced in LIFO order from their own job queue and before most other things in the event loop.

Then, I would explain that a few years ago, the spec was changed for some promise steps in the interest of improving performance and a JS engine before or after that spec change would likely generate different results for something like then.  Yet another reason why you shouldn't rely on that level of implementation detail.

If the interviewer insisted on me trying to explain the precise order in this problem and wouldn't listen to my reasoning why that's a pointless exercise, even after hearing my explanation for how I'd code a real world situation where execution order does matter, then unless this was just some really junior interviewer trying to be clever (and outsmarting themselves), I'd have to conclude this is not a good place to work.  No senior developer should insist that this is a super valuable or practical exercise beyond showing that you have a basic understanding of how the promise job queue works.

Comment: HEY Good point and very thankful!

But can you expain more about .....

" They run independently of one another and as soon as you insert any real world asynchronous operations in either of those promise chains (which all real-world programming would contain), then the timing of each chain is entirely unpredictable vs. the other....."

maybe give it a example? it is alien concept to me.

Comment: @Boison - I don't know where to start.  Asynchronous operations such as reading data from a file or fetching an http response from an external server all take an indeterminate and unpredictable time to complete so when you run multiple in flight at the same time, you cannot know ahead of time for sure which one will complete first.  This demo code does not contain real-world asynchronous operations.

Comment: yes I understand the order is random related to fetching to external server.  But Promise in there seems don't related to any external server.

Comment: @Boison - But this example code that has no actual asynchronous operations and is not useful code and would never be used like this in any real world programming problem.  Thus, it's not useful to understanding the gritty details.  Plus, if the order really matters, you wouldn't write it this way anyway.

Comment: I got it! I think maybe I can say this example use the tool(Promise) do something is not expected to do at the start.